# Can't get a property to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with 3 properties, as I mentioned in a previous question (this is a different question of course), the model called "Something" and it has 3 properties:

```
int SomethingID
string Name
List<System.Drawing.Color>
```

(of course it's not the original code, want to save some readers by saving some length)

And my **Initializer** is this:

```
protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
{
    var somethings = new List<Something>
    {
        new Something
        {
            Name="blah blah", Colors= { Color.Black, Color.Red }
        }
    };
        somethings.ForEach(s => context.Somethings.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
}
```

When I try to get those colors inside a view the colors are empty.
If I set a breakpoint inside the Initializer right after I constructed `somethings`, I get a property called `Colors` with a Count of 2 (so it's fine, I have the object with my ID, name, and colors).

But when it's inside the view, the debugger shows the `Colors`'s count is 0, and as you can guess - the list is empty.

**inside the View**

```
    Colors:
    @foreach (var itemColor in item.Colors)
    {
        itemColor.ToString();
    }
```

Desired result:
`Colors: Black Red`

Current result:
`Colors:` *(empty)*

Comment: I added to my answer below a translation property that will seamlessly translate a string of named colors to a list of system colors to and from the database. You just have to maintain your current list of system colors and the string property will translate it automatically, maintaining the state in your relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just listing the colors in code block but not writing them to the screen. try

```
Colors:
    @foreach (var itemColor in item.Colors)
    {
        @(itemColor.ToString())
    }
```

My favorite place to get quick reference for razor syntax
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

**EDIT**

Change your object to include this string property that will translate named colors to and from the database to your Colors List Property. This way your object is in full control of translating the information to the properties and you can continue using them as normal.

```
        public string SavedColors
        {
            get { return Colors.Aggregate("", (current, color) => current + (color.Name + ",")).TrimEnd(','); }
            set
            {
                Colors = value.Split(',').Select(Color.FromName).ToList();
            }
        }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<System.Drawing.Color> Colors { get; set; }
```

Comment: This would give me an error for writing @ inside where code. notice the bracers. beside that the view isn't the problem, since the debuger shows that the `Colors` property is empty.

Comment: well from the code you posted it looks like you are seeding a database with the colors. Are the values in the database? If they are what are code are you using in your controller to push to the view? The Controller is what determines what shows up in the view not your model builder.

Comment: How can I check if it's in the database? inside Visual Studio it doesn't have a coloumn but I think that's normal. (my controller was built from VS's template, didn't even touch it)

Comment: I'd have to recreate your code to test it out but from what I am seeing I bet your something object only has 2 columns, ID and Name, because the colors are in a list it would try to make a new table for Colors and then a bridge table to link them to the something items. Now I don't know for sure how System.Drawing.Color would get translated into a table row but I doubt it would be with the common names if it could do that at all. The standard controller is not going to know about the other related table unless you include it in your context objects, if it was even created properly.

Comment: Makes sense, but I don't see any other table with colors. I got the table for `Something` and table called `EdmMetadata` which I don't think it's what we're looking for.

Comment: yea I didn't think there would be as color doesn't match a known sql type.

Comment: Ok so where does it leave me? what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. If all you want to do is list out a bunch of color names just use a list of strings, you can always parse the string or hex name back to a color. You could even just build a long string of color names and then when you bring it back out of the database split it into a local array before converting back to colors. There are any number of ways to solve the problem, just not sure exactly what you are building so no way to tell what is best for your solution.

Comment: Look, all I'm trying is to pass a System.Drawing.Color property like I mentioned, and the database/view doesn't get it. I don't want to use alternatives.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, but a standard relational database which code-first uses is not going to be able to hold any object you throw at it. The balance is passing enough information in of the right types that when you pull that information back out you can recreate your original object. If you want to work with your objects as-is you will have to not use a relational database. I would give you a list of other DB's but that kind of work to integrate it with MVC is a whole lot harder than just restructuring your datatypes and recreating your objects in memory.

Comment: Oh, I see. actually makes more sense, thank you very much for your help and patience to explain this to me.